# PHP exec image processing not working within single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, imagemagick

I am trying to process an externally hosted image using a php command.

Here is the code:

```
exec('convert -resize "568x150" http://www.temp.com/temp.jpg scripts/newtemp.jpg');
```

If I run this command in it's own file called for example test.php in my wordpress directory then it works fine, resizes the image and saves it into the `/scripts` folder as newtemp.jpg

The problem occurs when I put this command into my `single.php`, then the codes doesn't seem to work and the image is not saved.

Is there an obvious reason this wont work within the `single.php`?

Comment: I'm guessing the `convert` may not be found in the `$PATH` when run via the web server.  Try with the `/full/path/to/convert -resize...`

Comment: Does this create an error? Try to see what's returned by exec.

Comment: We might need to see some code from `single.php` around the point where you call the `exec()` function. If it works in `test.php` the error should be in `single.php`.

Comment: Use full paths not only to call "convert", but also to refer to the output file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everybody, including the full path to both convert and to the image filename I was trying to save has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert is ImageMagick, right? You could just use its native [`php extension`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) and don't have to hassle with `exec`-ing it yourself.